# Create new folder in Google Docs with the new theme

Tags: google-drive

So I got upgraded to the newest theme in Google Docs (where all of the items are in the center pane).  I really like the folders, and I have had some setup before these improvements were added.  Now, I can't find the New Folder menu option under the Actions button anymore.

How can I create a new folder in Google Docs?

Answer (score 5):

The folders are now known as 'Collections' and can be created by clicking on the 'Create New' dropdown and then selecting 'Collection'.

More information is in *[Create a collection](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=68486)* (Google Docs Help).